# Code is unreachable after pd.concat - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I've getting a strange *warning* in VSCode after concatenating data that reads `Code is unreachable Pylance`.

I need to iterate over a df to send out each individual series as an output. **It needs to be row by row.**

After outputting the data though, I want to re-configure each individual series as a *datetime* and export it as a df.

It all works fine, but because *pd.concat* is looking for a list, everything beneath it is appearing as unreachable.

Is there a way to fix this? If it doesn't terminate the following functions, it may not be a big issue though.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Supplier': ['Costco','Walmart'],
       'Item': ['Apple','Orange'],
       'Cost': ['5','10'],
        })

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.now())

sent_data = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():

    print(i)
    print(row)

    # analyse data row by row
    # output data row by row

    sent_data.append(row)

    all_data = pd.concat(sent_data, axis = 1).T

    all_data.to_csv('export.csv')

    print(sent_data)
```

[image]

Comment: There's already an open issue about this - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/888 which is an interesting read (and see the linked pylance issues)

Comment: Mmm thanks. Lively debate. In two minds still.

Comment: Hopefully there will be a resolution soon enough. But in the meantime, if you are looking for a temporary solution like me, you can at least turn off the "showUnused" setting in VSCode.